# Add a user to a domain group and set the user privileges to certain folder

Tags: cmd, permissions, active-directory, windows-10, privileges

I have a user in my workplace domain, I want to add him to a specific domain group then assign him some privileges on a specific folder.

I wonder how this can be done using command line or a more automated process than doing it step by step as I do this quite often.

I'm using AD on Windows 10

Looks like [`dsmod group`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc732423(v=ws.10)) can be used but I don't know how.

If I have a user with username `userh01` in domain `mydom` how I can add him automatically to group `mydomgroup1`?

I've tried this command:

```
dsmod group "mydomgroup1" -addmbr "userh01"
```

but I get this error

> dsmod failed:Value for 'Target object for this command' has incorrect format.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using powershell to add memeber to a domain group is an alternative way.
here below th script for example
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "Groupmane" -Memebers "Username to add" 
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "mymdomgroup1" -Memebers "userh01"

ps:you may need to import active diretory modul. before using Add-ADGroupMeber parameter use this command 'Import-Module ActiveDirectory' at begining

for different syntax and detailed description to add-adgroupmember parameter follow this link 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/ee617210(v=technet.10)